# Polymorphism not working in PHP

Tags: php, polymorphism

I have a class which implements an interface.

Interface:

```
interface BaseDAO {
    public function persist(Model $model);
    public function merge(Model $model);
    public function delete($id);
}
```

Class' method:

```
public function persist(Partner $partner) { ... }
```

The Partner class implements the Model interface also, but it doesn't work for me. (Also tried Model as an abstract class and vice-versa)

The error that I get:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of RegisterDAO::persist(Partner $partner) must be compatible with BaseDAO::persist(Model $model) in C:\xampp\htdocs\be\dao\registerDAO.php on line 10
```

Thank you!

Comment: As the error says the method must match the interface. Instead of type hinting a model try creating another interface that exposes just the methods needed by persist() and merge() and type hint that instead. Then have the Model implement that interface. Assuming Partner is an extension of the model (if not just make that implement the new interface too)

Comment: Sounds great, why I didn't think of that. Make it an answer dude.